# Difference between Mage::getSingleton('core/layout') and $this->getLayout()

Tags: layout, singleton

I've been reading some tutorials and some use:

```
$this->getLayout()
```

To get the current layout, while others use:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
```

I was wondering if there's any difference between the two approaches.

The calls are being run from a controller class that extends `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this->getLayout()` is a shortcut for `Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')`, so technically there is no difference.

But note that, `Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')` works everywhere, while `$this->getLayout()` only works in controllers or blocks, i.e. classes that implement this shortcut method.